# Split df row into multiple rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an inconvenient dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame("200, 300", "5.367, 4.724", "50.87, -135.75")
```

I would like to split this dataframe into two rows:

```
df <- data.frame(c("200", "300"), c("5.367", "4.724"), c("50.87", "-135.75"))
```

But I can't make it happen. I've tried it with `separate_rows` or `strsplit`, but that won't work:

```
colnames(df) <- c("a","b","c")
d <- separate_rows(df, a, sep = ", ") %>%
  separate_rows(df, b, sep = ", ") %>%
  separate_rows(df, c, sep = ", ")
```

or

```
d <- lapply(df, strsplit(df, ","))
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `tidyr::separate_rows` can take tidyselect specifications (if it isn't new in the package, it's something I've overlooked until now), you can just use `everything()` to separate all columns. Or whatever other subset of columns you might need, without selecting them one by one.

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame("200, 300", "5.367, 4.724", "50.87, -135.75") %>%
  setNames(letters[seq_along(.)])

df %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(everything(), sep = ",") %>%
  mutate_all(readr::parse_number)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>       a     b      c
#>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1   200  5.37   50.9
#> 2   300  4.72 -136.
```

Answer (score 2):

This could all be combined into one dplyr pipe with:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   setNames(., c("a", "b", "c")) %>%
   mutate_all(~ strsplit(., "[,[:space:]]+")) %>%
   mutate_all(~ as.numeric(.))
#     a     b       c
# 1 200 5.367   50.87
# 2 300 4.724 -135.75
```

---

If you don't want dplyr pipes, then ... assuming that all will have the same number of elements, we can do this:

```r
df[] <- lapply(df, function(a) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(a, "[,[:space:]]+"))))
df
#     a     b       c
# 1 200 5.367   50.87
# 2 300 4.724 -135.75
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. You can use id variables based on the rows and then use `pivot_longer()` and `pivot_wider()` to obtain the desired output. Here the code using `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df <- df %>% mutate(id=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  separate_rows(value,sep=',') %>%
  mutate(value=as.numeric(trimws(value))) %>%
  group_by(id,name) %>% mutate(id2=1:n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=value) %>%
  ungroup() %>% select(-c(id,id2))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      a     b      c
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1   200  5.37   50.9
2   300  4.72 -136.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `tidyverse` (`dplyr` and `stringr` in particular)

```
df %>% mutate_all(str_split, ",", 2) %>%      #split everything - creates a vector in each cell
  unnest(cols = everything()) %>%             #converts to one per row
  mutate_all(~as.numeric(str_trim(.))) %>%    #remove spaces and make numeric
  set_names(c("a", "b", "c"))                 #set column names

# A tibble: 2 x 3
      a     b      c
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1   200  5.37   50.9
2   300  4.72 -136.
```